# Oracle: named java procedures, scoped by schema name?

Tags: java, oracle, loadjava

If I do this:

```
 loadjava -u user1 MyClass.class
 loadjava -u user2 MyClass.class
```

are the two class definitions distinct?  i.e., I can install a new version into user2 without affecting the code referenced by user1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You load java class into different schema - this is different objects - if you update one of this object second don't suffer.
I loaded jar many time on test and enterprise schema in same Oracle instance.